# How do I check if the sql command returns null or a value?

Tags: java, sql, database

```
try{
        Statement stm = conn.createStatement();

        String sql = "SELECT * from BOOKS WHERE ISBN_No = '" + line + "'";
        ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery(sql);
        if(//values are returned) {
            displayBookInfo(line);
        }
        else (//if it is null) {
            System.out.println("No book found");
        }
        stm.close();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Fail to search the book" + line );
        noException = false;
    }
```

After I execute the ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery(sql); I want to check if the query returned a value or if it was empty so that I can execute either "display book details" or "no book found message". I am just confused about how I should compare and how comparison works.

Comment: Use a parameter instead to pass the input value.

Comment: `if (rs.next()) { // input found }`. Incidentally, no need for the overhead of `SELECT *`. Just the key column will do

Comment: A result set is a "tabular data structure". That means it consists of rows, each one including multiple fields. Do you want to check for the existence of rows or for the value of a specific field?

Comment: @g00se – Your comment provides the best answer to the question, and I would like to upvote it … but as it is a mere comment, that is useless …

Comment: I can post it as an answer. But the comment about using `PreparedStatement` is important too AND includes my comment

Comment: I want to check if there exists a record that has an ISBN number that matches the value line. If yes,  "line" will be passed and I will extract the record details and show it on the displayBookInfo() module. So check if it returns null or a value and how do I do it?

Answer (score -1):

This **code is a security leak**. You must fix this first.

You cannot include untrusted inputs in a query like this. What if someone enters, say:

```
1234'; DROP TABLE books CASCADE; EXECUTE 'FORMAT C: /Y'; --
```

In the web form? Don't try it, you'll wipe your disk. You get the point, surely.

The right way is to use `stm.prepareStatement(sql)`, where `sql` is *a constant* (so not something you insert user entered stuff into), using a `?` where user input is needed, then calling `.setString(1, line)` to then tell your db driver what should go in place of the question mark.

Then, simply `rs.next()`, which advanced to the next row in the result (first call advances to the first row). If there are no rows left, it returns false instead. Hence, if your query returns 0 rows, the first `resultSet.next()` call returns false right away.

Your code also fails to close. You must use try-with-resources on everything (ResultSet, (Prepared)Statement, and most importantly the Connection), or your app will crash after a few statements.

NB: Minor nit, if all you want to know is if there's at least one result, add `LIMIT 1`, and just `SELECT 1 FROM` instead - it's less overhead that way.

Comment: From where did you guess that `line` was not checked properly before? Also your recommendation to use a `PreparedStatement` did not help to answer the question. Same as the recommendation to close: closing the `Connection` instance will close all the dependent objects, too, so without knowing the wider context, this recommendation was obsolete.

Comment: @tquadrat going: "Eh, I know this input is fine, we can just use plain statements here" flies in the face of every security recommendation for obvious reasons. This answer __answers the question__, and provides security advice as well. You suggest 'fixes' to this answer to makes everything worse. I disagree with all of what you said; this answer would get worse if I follow any of your advice.

Comment: You do not even know whether this code is in the context of a web application, but your first sentence is "This code is a security leak", before you you even mention the core of the question.

Comment: Yup. Security is hard enough as is without delving into "Weeeelllll, SQL injection is okay if you're sure the input is safe".

Comment: I am basically developing a library application. The database is already there and adding and deletion are not allowed. There is a search book, rent/return book, renew deadline and book reserve only. It's not a web form just a command-line interface form for a group project.  The rs will only get a single value if the line matches with a book in database.

Comment: Nothing in that comment is in any way or form a good excuse to forego basic security principles here. Fix your code to use PreparedStatement. It's security: Failure does not result in an app that doesn't work. Failure results in an app that works fine for a year or two and then sensitive private information leaks, or millions are lost. Don't look for the edge - do it right. Which is: PreparedStatement. The rest of my answer explains to you all you need to know: Call `.next()`.